# Which file/script runs first when i do helm install XYZ?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, package-managers, helm3

When I do hel install <app_name> which file or script among the chart.yaml, values.yaml or any other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that matters is the order in which resources are submitted to the Kubernetes cluster.  The `Chart.yaml` and `values.yaml` files do not contain any executable code and they don't "run" *per se*. Each of the files in `templates/` is processed independently, there is no global state, and a template file doesn't produce anything other than its YAML output, so the template files could be processed in any order or even all at the same time and you'd get the same result.

Helm does have [a specific order](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/484d43913f97292648c867b56768775a55e4bba6/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go#L24-L61) in which it submits different kinds of objects to a cluster.  These are intended to minimize problems from object dependencies being unresolved.  For example, a Deployment can reference a ConfigMap, so ConfigMap is early in that list and Deployment much later on.  Within each Kubernetes object kind, the objects are submitted in arbitrary order.